# Feather edge of image in with ImageMagick in 1 step (existing solution in 3 steps)

Tags: imagemagick, image-processing

I am trying to add a feathered edge to a JPG such that it fades to black at the edge of the image. I was able to achieve this in three steps, but have been struggling to combine it into one step.

1. Make a mask the same size as the equirectangular image.

```
convert image.png -fill white -colorize 100 -virtual-pixel Black -blur 0x64 -level 50,100% mask.png
```

2. Apply the mask to the original image, this creates a transparent feathered edge

```
magick image.png mask.png -alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite image_feathered_transparent.png
```

3. Convert to a jpg such that transparent areas appear black

```
magick image_feathered_transparent.png.png -background black -flatten image_feathered.jpg
```

**Feathering Example**

[image: IMG:]

In case you're curious, the perspective is weird because the image is intended to be viewed in VR. That's also why the feathering is helpful -- crisp edges look rather jarring in VR.

This workflow is based off two ImageMagick forum threads:

- Steps 1 & 2 from [Fading image edges - ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=33597)
- Step 3 from [Converting transparent PNG to Jpeg - ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=8359)

In the first thread Geemack suggests a solution to complete steps 1 & 2 in a single command, but I was not able to get it to work on my machine.

If relevant:

- MacOS 10.15.5
- ImageMagick 7.0.10-14 via Homebrew